# Running factory based on condition

Tags: angularjs

I have a log in screen that when the user enters the correct credentials will be able to get JSON data. For now I don't have a real API link. I'm just using dummy JSON data from a script file. The loginCtrl will pass parameters to the 'dummydata' factory which will make a 'GET' request. On success, the factor will pass the JSON data to the 'useData' function in the factory. This function in the factory is what all the controllers in my ng-view use.

The problem that I am having is that all the other controllers are calling 'dummyData.dashboardsData' and getting undefined because no one has logged in to pass data to that function. How can I prevent controllers (for example, navCtrl) from calling the factory until someone has logged in?

This is my index file:

```
<body ng-app="ciscoImaDashboardApp" ng-style="{'background-image': backgroundImg}" ng-controller="loginCtrl">

  <login></login>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <menu></menu>

</body>
```

This is my factory:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp').factory('dummyData', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {

var apiServices = {};

apiServices.login = function(user,password,callback) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'scripts/services/dummydata.js'})
    .success(function (response) {
        dataStatus = response.success;

        apiServices.useData(response);

        callback(dataStatus);
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        console.log("There was an error: " + error);
    });

};


apiServices.useData = function(response) {
    var data = response.data;

    apiServices.dashboardsData = data;
}


return apiServices;

}]);
```

This is my navCtrl:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp')
.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, navService, $location, dummyData) {

    var data = dummyData.dashboardsData;

});
```

This is my loginCtrl:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp')
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, dummyData, $location) {

    $scope.login = function() {

        var user_email = $scope.email;
        var user_password = $scope.password;

        dummyData.login(user_email, user_password, function (dataStatus) {
            if (dataStatus) {
                console.log("Success!");
                $scope.loggedIn = true;
                $location.path('/welcome');
            } else {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Consider having your service return the $http promise and **chain** off that promise -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises

Comment: @georgeawg can you show me an example how I would do that with my code?
Should I chain both functions in my factory? Or just one function in my factory to the controller?

Comment: I think you should start by looking at the articles about login recommended in the [AngularJS Developers Guide -- specific topics](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide#specific-topics). Then consider having `ng-route` abort views that require the user to be logged in. Abort to the login view if not logged in.

Comment: @georgeawg so I took the view that uses the navCtrl out of my ng-Routes. But since it is used in the body, the controller is called when loginCtrl is used. Is there any way to set a condition for the controller to trigger after loginCtrl OR render the nav view on success of the loginCtrl?

Comment: The `resolve` property of the route accepts promises. If one of the promises is rejected the route change will be aborted and the `$routeChangeError` event will be fired. For more information see the [AngularJS $routeProvider API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).